# Why is the next iCloud backup size so huge compared to the current one?

Tags: ipad, icloud, backup

I've factory reset (last month) my iPad 6th gen (now running iPadOS 16.5.1(c)) and created a new Apple ID with the basic storage plan (5GB). I have got iCloud backups enabled and it worked without problem for the past month.

I now get a warning in Settings: Under my Apple ID, it states "*Your iPad cannot be backed up*". When I click on this warning, a popup window with offers for iCloud+ appears, and, since I don't want to enlarge my subscription, I dismiss it.

Now comes the most surprising (and perhaps worrying) thing: In *Settings > [Apple ID name] > iCloud > iCloud Backups > [iPad name - This iPad]*, I see this:

[image: Screenshot taken on iPad of the backup details]

<sup>Click image to open full size</sup>

The current backup size is 289.9MB and the next backup size is 289.9MB ***+18.54GB***?!?

---

There are about 70 apps that have iCloud backups enabled and the one taking up the most space is weighing only **167.9MB**! All of the other apps take less than 35MB and most of them aren't even 1MB.

I haven't installed anything big or imported anything big to iCloud on this device since it got factory reset. Most of what I've imported is stored on the local storage "On my iPad", there are very few items (and they aren't weighing much) in iCloud.

**Note:** I haven't tried disabling/re-enabling iCloud backups and I would do it only if it's the last option.

---

So here comes the question:

- What can cause my next iCloud backup to be scheduled to weigh so much as the apps included in this backup do not justify it? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What does it say in iPad storage?  Can you get an image?

Comment: @DougMasters Nothing specific about iCloud backups - they aren't related afaik. Most apps do not consume too much storage for me. "On My iPad" uses over 18GB of storage but that is only the local storage, so unrelated to iCloud backups afaik. Here is a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGUn8.jpg

Comment: How much media and how many photos have you imported into the device?

Comment: @MarcWilson I've imported photos and videos (about 1,500 photos and 50 videos), pdfs (less than 150), mp3 files (about 100). I've imported all of this directly in "On my iPad", so local storage. I've still got some documents in iCloud Drive (1 pdf, 5 Numbers files, and 4 Reality Composer projects).  And about 15 contacts. I haven't imported anything else but I don't really see how this could affect my iCloud backups (only iCloud Drive and Contacts will affect).

Comment: If that media is local storage, it certainly does affect your backup size.  Items in iCloud Drive do not affect your backup size.

Comment: @MarcWilson Oh. Then the 18GB+ backup would be explained. The problem is that I've imported all of this stuff way before July 17th, I imported most of it (9/10th) between June 21st and June 22nd. Do you think there could be a delay?

Comment: So you're clear... iCloud Backup is not for backing up iCloud items.  It is for backing up items that are NOT in iCloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have just misunderstood the whole idea of iCloud Backups. Thanks to Marc Wilson, I've understood. Here is from one of [their comments](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/462365/why-is-the-next-icloud-backup-size-so-huge-compared-to-the-current-one#comment680892_462365):

> iCloud Backup is not for backing up iCloud items. It is for backing up items that are NOT in iCloud.

---

Just to sum up what's been said in the comments, I have imported quite a few photos, videos and other files to my local storage a few days before taking the screenshot in the question. That's probably why I say the +18G.

Answer (score 0):

In my case turns out that the iCloud backup size was giant due to full HD movie in the data folder of VLC Player. Although the movie was about 15 GB, VLC Player wasn't displayed on the top position in the iCloud backup details (the screen in the question). After removing the movie I managed to successfully backup to iCloud.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it is my Files app. It didn't show the size but I have some big files in it. After disabling then my backup can work.