What does the "Files" entry in an iPad's iCloud backup contain?
I have noticed a sudden drop in my iCloud Drive available space.
Browsing my iCloud options it was evident that the iPad's iCloud backup was to blame.
On the iPad, I browsed the backup and the top entry was the "Files" app, with a whopping 3.1 GB size!
To my knowledge, that should normally include all local files in non-cloud locations, but after browsing each folder in the "iPad" location, I have found nothing that—all summed together—would reach even 100 MB.
Is there any way I could understand what caused this sudden jump? Are locally downloaded files from iCloud being backed up? According to how iCloud Drive new FileProvider mechanism works, it should not because, on iPadOS (or iOS), we do not have the option to turn off "Optimise Storage" like we have on macOS.

For info: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/462365/489896

Well... in case you have not read my post, the "Files" app says there are 3.1 GB to back up, but in Files > iPad there is no trace of that amount. So, no, it's not that.

Yes, that's why I said "for info"
